# Allowing user to change password without enforcing password change

Tags: passwords, active-directory

I have a handful directory user accounts that should not require password change every few months. However, the user should be able to change it if he wishes to (especially since we send out initial passwords in clear text).

In AD, there is an option "password never expires", which should do exactly that, but it doesn't. Checking it disallows changing the password (although there's a separate "user cannot change password" checkbox).

The general policy that users should have to change password should not be affected, except for a few accounts. How can I achieve that?

Answer (score 0):

> I have a handful directory user accounts that should not require password change every few months.

Ensure that the setting **Password never expires** is checked in the user's AD object properties.

> However, the user should be able to change it if he wishes to (especially since we send out initial passwords in clear text).

Ensure that the setting **User cannot change password** is *not* checked in the user's AD object properties.

> The general policy that users should have to change password should not be affected, except for a few accounts.

You cannot use tools such as Group Policy to configure either of these settings for a group of users. Instead you must change the setting by directly editing the AD user object of the targeted user(s).

You can edit both of these settings for multiple users at once by selecting all of the users in the ADUC snap-in, then right-click one of the selected users and choose **Properties**. Changes made in the dialog that opens will affect all of the selected users.

To edit properties of multiple users that cannot be simultaneously selected in ADUC, consider a command-line tool such as ADMOD.

---

For new accounts created in the future, consider using templates to create the users. You could have one template called *Password Expires User Template* and another called *Password Does Not Expire User Template*. Then set your options appropriately in each template.

Using a template in ADUC is simple:

1. Create a dummy user account to serve as your template. Set the desired options for users created from the template. Also, disable the account.
2. To create a user from the template user, simply copy the template account to create a new user. Customize the new user as desired and enable the account. The new account will have the same settings that were configured on the template object.

This is an excellent way to ensure new accounts are created in a uniform fashion, even when multiple administrators are responsible for adding new users to the domain.

Comment: I have set the checkboxes as you said: https://i.imgur.com/dQshwDY.png , but I still cannot change the password: https://i.imgur.com/8SilZkp.png The new password fulfils the minimum requirements, the error message is misleading, and I can change the password of that account once I uncheck the "password does not expire" checkbox.

Comment: Can you translate the text of the dialog in the second image you provided?

Comment: "The password you entered doesn't meet the minimum security requirements."